# serialize javascript code inside html tags

Tags: javascript, json

I have an ajax function that responds with contents of an html tag, as a json string that I will eval to make an object out of it.

Now as long as the json string has no javascript inside it, it works fine. But when I include some simple javascript inside the string, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` when I try to eval the string, although I escape every `'` and `"`.

Here is the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/dCtA3/2/

When I remove the javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/dCtA3/3/ it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it using proper JSON (if your XHR returns JSON, use that, parse it, or check if the browser didn't parse it already for you (should be `[response].innerhtml`)). Change your jsfiddle code to:

```
var contents = JSON.stringify(
  {innerhtml : "<p onclick=\"javascript:alert('hello world');\"> click me! </p>"}
);

function insertContent() {
    document.getElementById("container")
        .innerHTML = JSON.parse(contents).innerhtml;
}​
```

[**Edit** based on comment]
see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/HcadL/) where a json request is simulated on button click. The stringified response object is shown after clicking the button.

Comment: the thing is the actual format of the reponse is like this:`{ contents: [{id: "some id", content: "somecontent"}, ... ]}`

Comment: Then you should retrieve the content you need, e.g. something like `response.contents[0].content`. If it's well formatted, it should be no problem to insert it as innerHTML into some `<div>` element, as my jsfiddle fork demonstrated.

Comment: the response comes in a string, I cant `eval` it correctly, how can i say `response.contents[0].content`

Comment: I can't say much more without seeing the actual code. You have an ajax function from which JSON is returned. A modern browser converts that to a proper object, so `eval`ling shouldn't be necessary at all. Even if  a JSON-string is returned, you don't need `eval`, but `JSON.parse`

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, as it seems that the problem is with me not being able to parse the response string, but can you tell me how I can parse a string like this `"{ innerhtml : \"<p onclick=\"javascript:alert(\'hello world\');\"> click me! </p>\" }";` to an object? the response is a simple string and not parsed before I do. just curious...

Comment: Change the escaping in your string. This should work: `JSON.parse('{"innerhtml" :"<p onclick=\\"javascript:alert(\'hello world\');\\">click me!<\/p>"}')`

Comment: yep that worked, so I should put `innerhtml` inside `"` too thanks! maybe you should add that to the answer too. can you tell me why exactly I should escape `"` twice around the js?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need your javascript code to be generated and does it HAVE TO be in that string? If the javascript can be in your js file you can simply do this:
make a function helloWorld that does the alert, and in your json string with html hance onclick="helloworld()".

Comment: yes the js must be retrieved from server as it will update some values and do stuff that are not static

Comment: this doesn't work, if I try your idea, I will have to atleast do `onclick="javascript:say('something');"` I mean there must be a kind of argumrnt to the function, but i still get the same error.